# number of non-isomorphic rings of order $135$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is the number of non-isomorphic rings of order $135$?

Can anyone tell me how can I able to solve this problem and which theorem or results are helpful? Thanks for your help.

More generally, can anybody tell me how many non-isomorphic rings there are for all orders?

Comment: Do rings have multiplicative identities for you?

Comment: may or may not. I get a example as $Z_{135}$.but how can I find all the non isomorphic rings

Comment: The number of (isomorphism classes) of rings with unity and $n$ elements is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A037291 but only up to $n=63$. There are $12$ for $n=27=(135)/5$, and I'd guess there'd be more for $n=135$.

Comment: priti - FYI: if you find an answer to be helpful, you may "accept it": you can accept one answer per  question asked. To accept an answer, click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you want to accept. I think you have enough rep, too, to upvote helpful answers, (as many as you wish).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825661

Answer (score 2):

According to the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A027623), the number of rings (up to isomorphism) with $n$ elements is a multiplicative function, so $f(135)=f(5)\cdot f(27)=2\cdot 59=118$.

Comment: can you please explain how did you find the values of $f$

Comment: By reading the list in the OEIS.

Comment: Nice - number of rings with unity is evidently *not* multiplicative.

Comment: I've never used OEIS: the keyword "mult" is intended to flag multiplicative sequences?

Comment: @rschwieb: [yes](http://oeis.org/eishelp2.html#RK)

Comment: @ChrisEagle Thanks!

Comment: Hint: The theorem to use is the Basis Theorem For Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, which will give you all possible additive groups of the ring from the prime factorization.