# number of rings of order 35

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

How many associative rings(with unity) of order 35 are there upto isomorphism? I think the answer is one. This is because there is just one abelian group of order 35. Is my reasoning right. Note that I have read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297945/number-of-non-isomorphic-rings-of-order-135) but it did not serve my purpose as no proof was given there. Thanks beforehand

Comment: Do your rings have a unity?  If so, there is only one ring of order $pq$, but your reasoning is not adequate—yes, we know the additive structure, but why does that tell us the multiplicative structure? (also, there are three other non-unital examples)

Comment: There is the ring where every product evaluates to $0$, for instance.

Comment: @Slade yes the rings consist of unity. edited the question.

Comment: @Arthur so are there many rings without the unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring of order $pq$, with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes.  As you have observed, $(R,+) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/pq,+)$ as abelian groups.

To show uniqueness of the ring structure, it is enough to show that $1\in R$ is an additive generator, as then the morphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ is surjective, so $R\cong \mathbb{Z}/pq$ as rings.

But there exists an element $x\in R$ of additive order $pq$.  If $1+\cdots + 1 = 0$, then $(1+\cdots + 1)x = x+\cdots + x = 0$, so $1$ has order $pq$ as well.

More generally, for non-unital rings, we can write $R\cong pR \oplus qR$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and consider the four cases where each of $pR$ and $qR$ are either cyclic or have trivial multiplication.

Comment: why does there exist an element of additive order $pq$?

Comment: Because of the isomorphism stated in the first paragraph.